# Sitecore form and list manager contact not saving properly

Tags: sitecore-forms, list-manager, marketing-automation, goals, segmented-list

I am using Sitecore form to subscribe to news. In the `On submit` of the form, I am triggering the goal. Once the goal is triggered, I have a marketing automation campaign which add the contact to the List Managers `SubscribeNews` contact list. I am seeing the contact being added in fields as `{{lastname}}`. `Firstname` and `Email` contacts are missing in SubscribeNews list as well.

I also added contact manually and it worked fine. Manually added contact have correct info in each field. I am only seeing issue with contact coming through marketing automation campaign.

I am using Sitecore 9.1.1. anyone having similar issue?

Also Once I have the contact in list manager, should the experience profile update from anonymous to real name/email?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are following below points:

1. In Sitecore form, you have selected `Update Contact Details` before `Trigger Goal`. You can follow https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-management/en/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-submit-action-that-updates-contact-details.html this link. `Update Contact Details` submit action will create/update contact in xDB.
2. After adding above submit action, make sure contact is showing in `Experience Profile` and you can see triggerd goal for that corresponding contact.
3. Make sure Marketing Automation is activated.

Answer (score 0):

[Sitecore form and list manager contact not saving properly](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18824/sitecore-form-and-list-manager-contact-not-saving-properlySo), do you remember? we use `GetValue(firstNameid)` to get the value out of id, make sure that you are getting proper value before

```
SetPersonalInformation(firstName, lastName, contact, client);
```

method is called, you might be calling `GetValue(firstName)` method twice but with actual value !!!

I would like to thank my lead for catching this silly mistake

Also Once I have the contact in list manager, should the experience profile update from anonymous to real name/email?
  Yes it does get updated, just make sure you saving data first and then triggering goal or whatever